# Unable to login at times on meta.unix.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, bug, stack-exchange, login

This is on meta. On certain questions like [Rename [screen] to [gnu-screen]](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/rename-screen-to-gnu-screen) I see the question but unable to put my preference or opinion on it as it says I'm logged into unix.stackexchange.com and stackexchange and elsewhere. I'm not even able to get a correct login page for the meta.unix.stackexchange.com site. Going to http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com is also unhelpful. I also tried registering in the hopes that something might be broken or dis-connected and maybe I had to re-register again but nothing. It dumps me right back to the homepage. I don't even get any questions for signing up.

Can somebody help.

Update - It is a HTTPS-Everywhere issue. After I take out the two HTTPS-Everywhere rules about stackexchange it works.

[image: HTTPS Everywhere drop-down box with rules]

Comment: Got HTTPS-Everywhere by any chance?

Comment: It would really help if you could add which browser and OS, including version you use, if you have any plugns enabled, if you have a direct connection or using VPN/TOR, if you are in a corperate network behind many proxies/firewalls, if the dev console shows any errors and verified that [all that is mentioned in *what else do I need*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) does work.

Comment: Browser Iceweasel - 36.0-1
OS - Debian Testing/Jessie. 
No VPN or TOR yet or network proxies or firewalls enabled. 

I am checking the link you shared.

Comment: I also opened up this because while it's part of the same issue, should have it's own question IMHO. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250620/messaging-failed-doesnt-give-more-info-as-to-what-to-do-about-it

Comment: I also opened up this because while it's part of the same issue, should have it's own question IMHO. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250620/messaging-failed-doesnt-give-more-info-as-to-what-to-do-about-it

@ShadowWizard you got it nailed on the first attempt I guess, but there are others (like this cross-document messaging thing) which also needs to be documented and understood.