# Messaging failed - doesn't give more info. as to what to do about it

Tags: support, login, authentication, auto-login, session

I am opening this so that if I run into the same situation would perhaps know what to do as well as others.

I am trying to login to sites and most sites work except for some meta sites. For this I was told to try https://meta.stackoverflow.com/network-login-help

where I failed test 3

```
Messaging **failed**

Your browser does not support the HTML5 postMessage feature, or it is disabled. Please make sure that you have a reasonably modern browser (e.g. IE8+, Chrome 4+, Safari 4+, FireFox 3.6+, Opera 10.61+), and that you don't have cross-document messaging disabled in your browser settings.
```

The failed is in red letters. I did go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Messaging which kinda tells what it does but doesn't tell me what to do in a failure nor thus the test page.

Addons used :-

a. HTTPSEverywhere 4.0.2  - https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/

b. RequestPolicyContinued 1.0.beta8.2 - https://github.com/RequestPolicyContinued/requestpolicy

The 3rd test seems to have something to do with https-everywhere

Update - The issue with networklogin test passes if https-everywhere is taken out so definitely the issue with either https-everywhere the addon (unlikely) or the HTTPS implementation at stackexchage (most probably) . If so, is there a place/ticket etc. where I can get news on the on-going implementation of HTTPS.

Comment: HTTPS is not fully supported yet and the tests do fail when you use HTTPS. If you use the HTTP version, the test passes for me.

Comment: The obvious question: did you make sure that you have a reasonably modern browser (e.g. IE8+, Chrome 4+, Safari 4+, FireFox 3.6+, Opera 10.61+), and that you don't have cross-document messaging disabled in your browser settings?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am using Iceweasel 36.0 or Firefox 36.0 so fully updated.  The part about cross-document messaging disabled in browser settings, how to check it and enable or disable it ? That one seems to be not available anywhere. I did check a few search-engines but came up empty. I have updated it in the main question as well.

Comment: @Won't that is precisely what I want to know, HOW TO know if cross-document messaging is disabled or enabled in browser settings. As shared my version is at par with what upstream (firefox) has released about a week back.

Btw, I was able to login once I removed the rule for stackexchange in https-everywhere but for the login test the issue remains.

Comment: The network test page has some `http://`'s hard coded which prevents it from ever functioning over HTTPS even if the cross-document communication is working.